# Regexp to extract paths between slashes in a long URL

Tags: sql, regex, url, path, extract

I am fairly new to regexp functions. I am using SQL-syntax to try and extract certain paths of an URL.

Example of URL:

```
https://www.test.com/private/how-to-extract/certain/paths/with-regexp.html
                        1         2            3      4          5
```

So my first column should include path nr 1: private
The second column path nr 2: how-to-extract
Third column: certain
Fourth column: paths
Fifth column: with-regexp

I have tried the following:

```
,replace(regexp(URL, '(.*?)\/(.*?)', '$2'), '%20', ' ') as path1
,replace(regexp(URL, '(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)', '$3'), '%20', ' ') as path2
,replace(regexp(URL, '(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)', '$4'), '%20', ' ') as path3
,replace(regexp(URL, '(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)', '$5'), '%20', ' ') as path4
,replace(regexp(URL, '(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)', '$6'), '%20', ' ') as path5
```

I think I dont quite understand how the regexp-function of certain paths operates...

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `INSTR` function, which get n's occurrence of substring.

```
INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [, nth_appearance ] ] )
```